# How to map request payload to Tuple in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, c#-7.0, namedtuple

Below is my endpoint

```
// D - Delete
[HttpPost,HttpDelete]
[ProducesResponseType(204)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromBody](int eventId, int personId, DateTime purchaseDate) reqTO)
{
   if (reqTO.eventId > 0 && reqTO.personId > 0 && reqTO.purchaseDate!= null)
   {
      var (flag, msg) = await _someRepository.Delete(reqTO.eventId, reqTO.personId, reqTO.purchaseDate);
      if (flag)
      {
         //204
         return CreateResponse<(int eventId, int personId, DateTime purchaseDate)>("Entry removed successfully", HttpStatusCode.NoContent, reqTO);
      }
      else
      {
            //TO DO
      }
   }
   else
   {
      return BadRequest();
   }
}
```

Now when I am calling this Endpoint from the postman with the below request payload

```
{
"eventId": 1,
"personId": 3,
"purchaseDate": "2019-01-04T18:25:43.511Z"
}
```

The Endpoint is hit, but the values assigned in the request payload are default values like `eventId =0 ,personId =0 & purchaseDate = {01-01-0001 00:00:00}`.

**NOTE:** I don't want to create any DTO.
**How do I map ReqPayload to Named Tuple??**

Answer (score 1):

`[HttpDelete]` will ignore the `request body` so you are getting default values.

Use `FromUri` and pass values in parameter.

Or use `[HttpPut]` or `[HttpPost]` if you want to pass in `request body`.

Check this question hopefully it will be helpful.
[Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Comment: No Karan!! checked with HttpPost still the same issue